# Does a slime block have custom Attributes?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I was just wondering if slime blocks have their own attributes such as Bounciness ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Slime blocks are not tile entities, so they have no attributes (nor any other NBT data) that can be modified by commands.

A list of tile entities and their tags can be found here:
https://minecraft.wiki/w/Chunk_format#Block_entity_format